# Can't update my Database have a int column name

Tags: php, mysql, database

My table name is 'result' and have a column name '1'
now i want to update this.

My code is

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE result
    SET 1 =  'hello'
    WHERE id = '$no'   
");
```

// $no=$_GET['id'];

Comment: @pavan that edit you're attempting http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10598001 is clearly a violation of Stack rules *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."*. Edit rejected. Please don't do that again. The question was closed accordingly.

Comment: just ADD tilde sign to tell mysql that `1` is column name not an integer.

Comment: You have to use back quotes for funky column names, e.g. `\`1\` , \`sum(foo)\`, etc...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- - That edit was classic lol he just took over the OP question ^__^ can we frame that ? lol

Comment: @andre3wap If the frame fits, why not ;-)